# Extract milliseconds from traceroute with Bash for later data processing (with Python)

Tags: bash, awk

I want to extract all millisecond values for the hops that traceroute generates in Linux (version 2.0.21). The expected output I want is as follows:

```
xx
xx
xx
xx
```

where xx denotes milliseconds ***for each hop in the traceroute execution***, no blank characters before or after. For reference, example pure `traceroute` output:

```
2  100.66.0.254 (100.66.0.254)  13.592 ms 100.66.0.208 (100.66.0.208)  15.711 ms 100.66.0.216 (100.66.0.216)  21.187 ms
3  100.66.0.21 (100.66.0.21)  21.266 ms 100.66.0.31 (100.66.0.31)  21.223 ms 100.66.0.29 (100.66.0.29)  21.183 ms
```

My attempted solution is this code which is not working for all the `traceroute` output.

(Input)

```
traceroute adomain.com | awk '!/traceroute/ {print $4;'}
```

The field `$4` is not always the millisecond value, depending on the hop characteristics. Please see below:

(Output)

```
13.592
21.266
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) <- Denotes when $4 is not a timestamp.
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
*
*
```

(xxx used to garble the IP in question).

So, above you can see that for the last four entries I'm not getting the millisecond values.

Is there an awk or sed solution for this?

PS I'm posting this on StackOverflow, because this task is part of a data gathering task, and the data will be used in a grander programming context.

Comment: Could you please elaborate here, `33.252` from output is not present in sample input? Is it you need all values which are coming before ` ms` in output?

Comment: The sample pure output is for another traceroute - The syntax of the output is clear..

Comment: Since you're going to be post-processing the output with python, why not do this step in python too? It's important when posting an example that the output you provide is the output you expect from  the input you provide, not the output from some other input. Make your question (and example) as clear and simple as possible to minimize how much time people have to spend trying to understand your problem and so get the most people willing to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @EdMorton, I want to use Bash to extract output from Linux commandline tools. I save Python for data tasks (ETL) that does not involve Linux commandline output. Naturally, this is only a preference, and I'm not saying everyone "should" think or approach it like that.

Comment: Fair enough, then just [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input if you'd like help. I know you got 1 answer so far, I've no idea if that's the best answer you could get though or even the right answer as I don't see how it could produce the format of output you say you want (Where would that script output IP addresses? How can it handle multiple ms per line? Should it? What are those `*`s in your expected output?). Even if you're happy with the answer you got, fixing your question would help the next person with a similar question to find their answer too

Comment: Very true, I did not realize that, my apologies. I have edited the question and added an 'expected output' sentence followed by my solution attempt and how it was not entirely what I was looking for. Thank you for highlighting, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding a solution in case anyone wants to get multiple miliseconds in a single line too in output then one could try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ms/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-6)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Since you have not shown exact sample output so this command is being provided based on your explanation only.

```
traceroute adomain.com |\
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ms/){print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-6)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ms/){           ##Using match with regex to match digits DOT digits space ms in a line.
  print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-6)    ##If a match if found then RSTART, RLENGTH variables are SET(which are default awk variables).
                                         ##Then I am printing sub-string which starts from RSTART+3 till value of RLENGTH-3
}
'  Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem and produces the output as described in my 'expected output' sentence in the description of the problem.